# How to push certain branches into git repository?

Tags: git, svn

I'm trying to convert svn repository into git. I've already cloned svn repository on local computer. And now trying to push it into git. Here are my steps:

```
git remote add origin https://my-gitlab/myproject.git
git branch -a
git tag

git push origin master feature_1 feature_2 feature_n tag_1 tag_2 tag_n
```

And i got error on push

```
error: src refspec feature_1  does not match any
error: src refspec feature_2  does not match any
error: src refspec feature_n  does not match any
error: src refspec tag_1  does not match any
error: src refspec tag_2 does not match any
error: src refspec tag_n does not match any
```

So i can't push it into git.

I've run `git show-ref` and found all my branches in the output list.
Also when i ran `git branch -a` i noticed that all my braches are red but can't find any information if it ok or not.

Previously i've already convert smaller svn repository into git with the same commands. But now i can't find what i'm doing wrong?

*UPDATE* git branch -a output

```
git branch -a
* master
  remotes/svn/feature_1
  remotes/svn/feature_2
  ....
:...skipping...
* master
  remotes/svn/feature_1
  remotes/svn/feature_2
  ....
:

* master
  remotes/svn/feature_1
  remotes/svn/feature_2
  ....
(END)
```

Comment: ok.... you _probably_ have the svn branches tied to non-local branches... is that the case? The syntax you are using there (`git push some-remote branch1`) **requires** that you have a local branch called `branch1` setup.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the actual output of `git branch -a`?

Comment: @larsks git branch -a output added

Comment: @eftshift0 I've used command svn2git https://my-server/svn/Sources/my-svn-project --trunk trunk --tags tags --branches branches --no-minimize-url to copy svn repository. But i don't know if it actually clonned branches to local computer. But as i mentioned in the question it works for small project. I guess i just not experienced with git enough to ask correct question.

Comment: From output of the list of branches... and _assuming_ that the branches do not exist on the remote you are trying to push into, you should try: `git push origin svn/feature_1:refs/heads/feature_1`, for example. It might be worth setting it up as an answer, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Locally*, the svn branches, from the output you provided there, they are setup as being on the *remote* `svn`. Now, in order to push a branch `svn/some-branch` into `origin` *and* assuming that the branch does **not** exist in the `origin` remote yet, you have to do it like this:

```
git push origin svn/some-branch:refs/heads/some-branch
```

That should work to push the branches (just provide multiple branches in a single push... or separate push commands).

Comment: Thank you. Now command is working. But i gues i messed with tags. I used git push `origin master svn/feature_1:refs/heads/feature_1 svn/tags/tag_1:refs/heads/tag_1` and all tags appears as branches. Is it possibel to fix it?

Comment: Oh i figure out i should use `svn/tags/tag_1:refs/tags/tag_1` for tags.